# 2X2 matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

$vw^T = \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2   \\  10 & -5 \end{bmatrix}  v,w ∈R^2$

How each of the four matrix elements depends on the 2 components of ***v*** and of ***w***?

I want to know the solution to get ***v*** and ***w***.

$ \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^T$

$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^T$

I know the answer, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to revisit the definition of matrix multiplication. In this case

$$vw^\top=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1w_1 & v_1w_2 \\
v_2w_1 & v_2w_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

From that you can solve the equations

$$v_1w_1 = -4$$
$$v_1w_2 = 2$$
$$v_2w_1 = 10$$
$$v_2w_2 = -5$$